# Running android emulator during jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, android-emulator, continuous-integration, kvm

I have installed Jenkins and configured a build job with emulator running during build. But when I execute the job, I get error message that jenkins user doesn't have permission to run kvm. How can I fix it.

```
$ android list target
[android] Using Android SDK: /opt/android/sdk
$ adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5973 *
* daemon started successfully *
$ adb start-server
[android] Starting Android emulator
[android] Erasing existing emulator data...
$ emulator -ports 5971,5972 -prop persist.sys.language=en -prop persist.sys.country=US -avd hudson_en-US_160_1024x768_android-15_x86 -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -wipe-data
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure KVM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: This user doesn't have permissions to use KVM (/dev/kvm).
[android] Emulator did not appear to start; giving up
$ adb disconnect localhost:5972
[android] Stopping Android emulator
$ adb kill-server
```

Permissions

```
$ ls -l /dev/kvm
crw-rw----+ 1 root root 10, 232 May  6 13:46 /dev/kvm

$ groups jenkins
jenkins : jenkins
```

Comment: Run `kvm-ok` and see the output.
Is it
`INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used`
or
`INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
KVM acceleration can NOT be used`
? It also could be that `Enter your BIOS setup and enable Virtualization Technology`, so then you should do as said :)

Comment: As you've shown yourself, only `root` has permission to access `/dev/kvm`, and `jenkins` isn't in the `root` group.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I have managed to fix the problem.

1. Install Qemu-KVM and cpu-checker:
   `sudo apt install qemu-kvm cpu-checker`
2. Check if KVM is available (as `jenkins` user):
   `$ kvm-ok`
   `INFO: /dev/kvm exists`
   `KVM acceleration can be used`
3. Create group kvm and add `jenkins` to this group:
   `addgroup kvm`
   `usermod -a -G kvm jenkins`
4. Change group ownership for `/dev/kvm`:
   `chgrp kvm /dev/kvm`
5. Create udev rule:
   `$ sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/60-qemu-kvm.rules`
   `KERNEL=="kvm", GROUP="kvm", MODE="0660"`
6. Reboot

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/43731342/2482947. In ubuntu you should also add `jenkins` user to `libvirt` group.

Answer (score 0):

On my CI (gitlab) this was missing on Ubuntu

```
usermod -a -G kvm gitlab-runner
```

or with Jenkins

```
usermod -a -G kvm jenkins
```