# Android emulator is not listening to port while starting

Tags: android, ubuntu, jenkins, android-emulator

Jenkins cannot run an android emulator.

```
[android] Using Android SDK: /opt/android-sdk-linux
[android] Creating Android AVD: /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_240_WVGA_android-23_google_apis-x86_64.avd
[android] /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android create avd -f -a -s WVGA800 -n hudson_en-US_240_WVGA_android-23_google_apis-x86_64 -t android-23 --abi google_apis/x86_64
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb start-server

* daemon not running. starting it now at tcp:5837 *
* daemon started successfully *
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb start-server
[android] Starting Android emulator
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator -engine classic -ports 5682,5683 -report-console tcp:5827,max=60 -prop persist.sys.language=en -prop persist.sys.country=US -avd hudson_en-US_240_WVGA_android-23_google_apis-x86_64 -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -no-window
WARNING: Force to use classic engine to support snapshot.

[android] Emulator did not appear to start; giving up
[android] Stopping Android emulator
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb kill-server
Finished: NOT_BUILT
```

Then, I try to run emulator the same as jenkins. The problem is android emulator is not starting to listen to the port. First, I created and started emulator successfully with the 'user' user as follow:

```
user@host:~$android create avd -f -a -s WVGA800 -n test -t android-23 --abi google_apis/x86_64
Android 6.0 is a basic Android platform.
Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile [no]no
Created AVD 'test' based on Android 6.0, Google apis Intel Atom (x86_64) processor,
with the following hardware config:
hw.lcd.density=240
hw.ramSize=512
vm.heapSize=48
user@host:~$ emulator  -avd test -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -no-window
WARNING: Force to use classic engine to support snapshot.
emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
[139763360147200]:WARNING:./android/base/files/IniFile.cpp:158:Failed to process .ini file /home/user/.android/emu-update-last-check.ini for reading.
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: No error
none.xml:1: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
amp;uid=&amp;os=Linuxversion=25.2.5.0&amp;coreVersion=qemu1%200.10.50">Found</a>
                                                                               ^
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: failed to get the latest version, skipping check (current version '25.2.5-3567187')
```

So everything is okey with 'user' user, but for 'jenkins' user I have problem

```
jenkins@host:~$ android create avd -f -a -s WVGA800 -n test -t android-23 --abi google_apis/x86_64
Android 6.0 is a basic Android platform.
Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile [no]no
Created AVD 'test' based on Android 6.0, Google apis Intel Atom (x86_64) processor,
with the following hardware config:
hw.lcd.density=240
hw.ramSize=512
vm.heapSize=48
jenkins@host:~$ emulator  -avd test -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -no-window
WARNING: Force to use classic engine to support snapshot.
emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
```

and that is it! No matter how much I wait the line of "emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554" is not coming!

BTW, kvm is running okey for both users

```
$ kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
```

Also, "ANDROID_HOME" and "HOME" environment parameters are okey.

Any suggestion?

**UPDATE**

I noticed this problem is not happening when I'm using `google_apis/armeabi-v7a` abi. So I believe this problem is related to kvm installation, but I have not idea how to fix it.

```
jenkins@hosst:~$ android create avd -f -a -s WVGA800 -n test -t android-23 --abi google_apis/armeabi-v7a
Android 6.0 is a basic Android platform.
Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile [no]no
Created AVD 'test' based on Android 6.0, Google apis ARM (armeabi-v7a) processor,
with the following hardware config:
hw.lcd.density=240
hw.ramSize=512
vm.heapSize=48
jenkins@host:~$ emulator -avd test -no-window
WARNING: Force to use classic engine to support snapshot.
emulator: WARNING: System image is writable
emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.
[140306725234432]:WARNING:./android/base/files/IniFile.cpp:158:Failed to process .ini file /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/test.avd/snapshots.img.default-boot.ini for reading.
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
[140306725234432]:WARNING:./android/base/files/IniFile.cpp:158:Failed to process .ini file /var/lib/jenkins/.android/emu-update-last-check.ini for reading.
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: No error
none.xml:1: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
amp;uid=&amp;os=Linuxversion=25.2.5.0&amp;coreVersion=qemu1%200.10.50">Found</a>
                                                                               ^
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: failed to get the latest version, skipping check (current version '25.2.5-3567187')
```

**UPDATE #2**
After I successfully run the emulator and post my answer below, I fall to this problem again!! and my solution is not working anymore :( BTW I found another clue that I want to share it with you here. Following command is not starting to listen to the port as I mentioned before

```
android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator -avd test -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -no-window
```

But surprisingly, this command is running okey

```
android-sdk-linux/tools/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64 -avd test -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -no-window
```

I guess `emulator` should run `qemu-system-x86_64` but somewhere it makes some mistakes and run `emulator64-x86` instead. Event after this finding I cannot figure out how to put this command in `Android Emulator plugin`! So the question is open again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my update I had some clues that this problem is related to kvm installation. I was using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30098160/2482947) to install kvm. On the other hand, I noticed `user` user is a member of `libvirt` group which is related to kvm permissions. So I add `jenkins` user to `libvirt` group and bang! the problem solved.

```
usermod -a -G libvirt jenkins
```

Comment: For which Ubuntu version does that work? Ubuntu 18.04 has no `libvirt` group and `/dev/kvm` is owned by group `kvm` after installing `qemu-kvm`.